# In Android How to retain the text of all the textviews in the tableview on orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation, orientation-changes

In my android app, I am creating the Textviews dynamically(in java code) and binding them to a TableLayout. I have an async Task, to continuously update every textview's text. I am changing the text of these textviews on click. On orientation change, I want to retain the text of all the textviews in the tableview. During creation, I am giving unique ID to each textviews, I don't want to declare onConfigChanges in Manifest(Bad aproach). Can not go with OnSavedInstanceState() aproach also, as there are many textviews. So, I am trying with async task in a fragment. Please help me, how to achieve this.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use `ListView/RecyclerView`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10259838/115145, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545211/how-edittext-retains-its-value-but-not-textview-when-phone-orientation-changes/26685777#26685777, and others

Comment: I am sure LordRaydenMK. I dont wanna use Listview or Gridview or Recycler view.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I can not go with onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState.  Because, there are hundreds of textviews.